# Incorrect Odometer due to New Instrument Cluster - MOT Impact

Tags: odometer, mot

So I've seen these two questions that are related but don't answer my core worry:

[Incorrect odometer reading after replacing instrument cluster?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/12342/incorrect-odometer-reading-after-replacing-instrument-cluster)

[Used odometer supposedly showing incorrect reading](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/25574/used-odometer-supposedly-showing-incorrect-reading)

---

I've just bought a used 2018 Skoda Superb SE Tech. However, I really like the audi-style virtual cockpit that you can get on the highest trim model. So I'm looking to buy the part from AliExpress and then retrofit it. I've found a local retrofitter who's willing to recode it for me.

However, the car currently has about 80k miles on it. When I install this virtual cockpit, it'll have 0 miles on it. I know I can record the mileage on the old odometer and then disclose that to any future buyer should I sell it to avoid fraud. The crux of my concerns is that in the UK, the mileage on your car is reported when you have an MOT.

As such, will this discrepancy where the mileage has apparently shrunk, cause me any issues with MOT, insurance, the DVLA etc?

Comment: Have you read any info on the DVLA website? about changing the odo or effects for  MOT?

Comment: @SolarMike - I've looked but I've not been able to find anything relevant. I figured it would be such an unusual case they might not have publicly commented in an easy to find place

Comment: If the retrofitter can recode it why not get them to put the right mileage on the odometer?

Comment: I think recoding it just keeps the immobilizer happy, I don't think they can arbitrarily change the odometer

Comment: One thing that could be an issue is if it shows the incorrect speed. It must be matched to the transmission. In UK the speed shown must be within certain limits of accuracy - by law.

Comment: In California there is a form you give to the purchaser of your vehicle.  Either you certify that the odometer is correct as far as you know or you report what it should be.  As long as you keep track of the mileage that "disappeared" and report it accurately you are good to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No issue really.

You have a bill from the garage that would show the original odo reading and obviously state the new one was fitted. So the service history shows the cumulative mileage.

Never been a problem with those who are honest, just becomes an issue when people try to hide it and get found out.

Edit based on comment:
I changed more than a few as a vehicle auto-electrician, many under warranty (failed or wavering) and others far older. No reporting to the police needed, nor to insurance etc.

The cars (we had loyal customers) that we saw for MOT later would just have the indicated mileage recorded.

Comment: So essentially just make sure that it's noted in the service history and stamped off?

Answer (score 2):

In the classic car community it's not uncommon for people to fit a completely rebuilt and zeroed odometer either cause the fitted one breaks or they're completing a restoration and want to mark the 'new zero' for the rebuilt car. It's also pretty common for someone to fit a second hand one with a random mileage indicated cause that's what they have available. This has no impact on the MOT. The OP's only concern, as they've rightly stated, should be not misrepresenting the car's mileage to any future buyer (and said buyer will be able to see the mileage history on the [Gov MOT history check](https://www.gov.uk/check-mot-history) anyway, which is likely the point of recording it nowadays!)